# Ruby on rails custom method instead of index in a search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, methods

I have the index method and a custom method `new_method` on the same controller, on a api web service.

```
def new_method
  @books = Book.where(:type_id => params[:type_id]).order('name')
end
```

This renders to a JSON view.

On another web app I have this on a method.

```
def new_method
  @books = Books.all(:params => {:type_id => params[:type_id]})
end
```

This should render the data from the JSON view from the API web service to a HTML view in the web app.
However this is not doing what I expect because when I go to the url to view the html view I see nothing. Books from the web app goes to `books_controller#index` in the API web service instead of going to `books_controller#new_method`. If i change the name of `new_method` to `index` in the API web service I get what I expect. But I'm already using `index` for another purpose.

Is it possible to use the custom method instead of `index`?

Answer (score 0):

Rails allows you defining more routes under resources. Please check out this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for detail

In your case, you may define a custom route like this:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :books do
  # Your current routes
  collection
    get 'new_method'
  end
end
```

So your route to `new_method` will be:

```
/books/new_method
```

Comment: `controller: 'books', as: 'books', path: 'books'` ... this is all implied by `resources :books`, isn't it? Any reason you included it? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

Comment: @alexanderbird I see, just specify full options, btw, I update what you commented :), thanks for that

Comment: i have defined a route `get 'new_method_url' => books#new_method'` and im able to go to the `localhost:3000/new_method_url`

Comment: I mean you would update the detail of your routing (file `routes.rb`) and how did you call to your controller?